# How do I "go to" a referencing outlet's code from the XCode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Does anyone know how to quickly go to the code for a referencing outlet from the XCode storyboard's events/outlets sidebar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The outlet doesn't have any code. It's the IBAction link that points to code.

I haven't found a way to display the IBAction method automatically, but if you select the object (usually a button) and view the Connections Inspector, it will tell you the target and method name that is being invoked. You can then find that method in your project's source code.

Comment: As good an answer as any right now - my issue is that these are in a class with a name long enough to get truncated,so that particular feature isn't very useful.

Apple needs to give us the ability to command+click into the code from the storyboard!

Comment: Yeah! I was wandering about the same thing! It would be much simpler if you could go to the IBAction directly for storyboard. But apparently Apple does not support it. Such a shame

Comment: Wow, such simple thing still not supported! I started to code Delphi 12 years ago and even there you could click on any UI element to jump directly to code.